# Comparing regression coefficients using F-test to assess for batch effects

Tags: regression, pca, regression-coefficients, f-test

Here's what I have: two datasets with ~27,000 variables (same variables for each dataset).

I'm trying to test whether or not dataset1 and dataset2 display batch effects. Namely, I want to do PCA and do regression on the principal components, and then I want to compare the regression coefficients between datasets to see if there is significant difference between each dataset's "directionality".

The worry I have is: datasets are measuring the SAME measures (27k methylation probes) from people with different diseases. Can you find batch effects if the prediction variable (y) is not the same between the datasets being compared?

Secondly, I have read that an F-test can compare regression coefficients, but I'm not sure I understand how it works. If I do multiple comparisons where I ask:

```
Model 1: disease1 = B0 + B1*x_1 + B2*x_2 + ... + BN*x_n + error
Model 2: disease2 = b0 + b1*x_1 + b2*x_2 + ... + bn*x_n + error
H0_1: B0=b0
H0_2: B1=b1
....
H0_N: BN=bn
```

Isn't that just like doing N t-tests and then combining the p-values using a Fisher's combined p-value? How does the F-test handle the comparison of regression coefficients and how do you "verbalize" the null hypothesis of my situation described above? I'm self taught in statistics, and trying to learn, so any help would be appreciated!

Comment: What do you mean by "batch effects"?

Comment: Ah, so it's an easy thing to add confusion and I should have left it out. "Batch effects" occur often in the collection of -omics datasets when you have to run your samples on more than one bead chip. In my circumstances above, the samples were run in two different experiments with the same platform (i.e., no platform effects) and can be directly compared. Statistically, no platform effects=all measured variables are measuring the same thing. However, the part I'm worried about is each experiment is measuring subjects with different disease categories.

Comment: I'm not sure how I would - if I do detect batch effects - determine if the differences between the directionality of the datasets is due to the fact that each dataset measures different disease cohorts or if its due to "batch effects" (artibitrary variables like the temperature of the environment which the samples were tested in, lighting, the technician's specific web lab "quirks", etc.). Does this make sense? Good question!

Comment: Now I see. It makes sense, but I think the answer is negative: there is no way you can discriminate between the two...